# setting source of an image component not working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I'm pulling in a xml-file with just one result in it. One of the nodes is picture, which contains a link to a picture. This is the xml-file:

```
 <artist>
    <id>502</id>
    <name>Bad Religion</name>
    <picture>http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/500/46612615/Bad Religion BR 2010.jpg</picture>
    <twitter></twitter>
</artist>
```

I've tested the url, and it's correct. This is how I try to bind the url to the image instance (artistPic), but it's not working. Displaying the artist name does work.

```
var artist:XMLList = new XMLList(event.result);
artistPic.source = artist.picture;
lblArtistName.text = artist.name;
```

Comment: I think I've said this before: "It's not working" says absolutely nothing about what's wrong.  It is very hard, if not impossible, to help you, unless you provide more information.  To make this easier for you and everyone else, you could use the Flash Player Content Debugger plugin (just Google to find it), you could show any error messages, you could trace stuff to see where your variables are not being set correctly, and you _should_ at least provide the code for artistPic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `artist.picture` returns an XMLList object. Try the following code :

```
var artist:XML = new XML(event.result);
artistPic.source = String(artist.picture[0]);
lblArtistName.text = artist.name; // This one is probably transtyped automagically by Flex.
```